# redis time out error, getting a timeout error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am receiving a connection timeout error when attempting to access the Redis server at a rate of 5000 requests per second. Below is the code I am using:

```
public static class RedisCache
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> Connection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        var Configuration = builder.Build();
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect($"{Configuration["RedisConfig:Redis"]}", (c) =>
        {
            c.ClientName = Configuration["RedisConfig:ApplicationName"].ToString();
            c.DefaultDatabase = int.Parse(Configuration["RedisConfig:DatabaseId"]);
            c.Ssl = bool.Parse(Configuration["RedisConfig:Ssl"]);
            c.ConnectTimeout = int.Parse(Configuration["RedisConfig:ConnectionTimeoutInMilliseconds"]);
            c.ConnectRetry = int.Parse(Configuration["RedisConfig:ConnectRetry"]);
            c.AsyncTimeout = int.Parse(Configuration["RedisConfig:AsyncTimeout"]);
            c.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
            c.SyncTimeout = 50000;
        });
    });

    public static IDatabase Database => Connection.Value.GetDatabase();
}
```

please help me to correct the code.I looking for a proper design which hadeling more than 2000 request per second

Error Message

> Redis cacheThe timeout was reached before the message could be written
> to the output buffer, and it was not sent, command=GET, timeout:
> 50000, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, bw: CheckingForTimeout, rs:
> NotStarted, ws: Idle, in: 0, serverEndpoint:
> url:port, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10
> available, clientName: prod, IOCP:
> (Busy=11,Free=989,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER:
> (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=2,Max=32767), POOL:
> (Threads=26,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=23572563), v: 2.6.66.47313
> (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues
> that can cause timeouts:
> https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)

Comment: Does it work fine for less than 5000 rps?

Comment: @Chetan.it is failed for 1000 request

Comment: Did you verify the connection parameters? What type of redis server it is? Hosted on local or in some cloud?

Comment: @Chetan in hosted in a cloud

Comment: are you able to connect to it using redis insight tool?

Comment: Have you gone through the [documentation checklist for timeouts](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts.html)? And can you add the full error message to your question (as text)?

Comment: @stuartd Question updated with error message

Comment: And have you been through the checklist

Comment: @stuartd..yes but no hope

Comment: What is the spec of your cloud Redis server?